# Loop exits and go to next line in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to iterate the first line in "profile" to the first line in "arn" and then 2nd line "profile" to 2nd line in "arn", 3rd line in "profile" to 3rd line in "arn"

But my script check the first in profile file and loop all the contents in "arn" file. After finishing it will got to next line in "profile" and loop all the content in "arn"

```
#!/bin/bash

for profile in `cat ../../.aws/config|grep 'profile'`
do
        for arn in `cat policy_arn`
        do
                 aws --profile ${profile} iam delete-policy  --policy-arn ${arn}
        done
done
```

cat policy_arn

```
arn:aws:iam::37928052:policy/PointPolicy
arn:aws:iam::56433041:policy/PointPolicy
arn:aws:iam::18225202:policy/PointPolicy
arn:aws:iam::908231278:policy/PointPolicy
arn:aws:iam::441043922:policy/PointPolicy
arn:aws:iam::227661653:policy/PointPolicy
```

profile

```
dev-ops
pro-ops
qc-ops
```

OUTPUT

should be

```
first loop arn=arn:aws:iam::37928052:policy/PointPolicy and profile=dev-ops
2. arn=arn:aws:iam::56433041:policy/PointPolicy profile=pro-ops
3. arn=arn:aws:iam::18225202:policy/PointPolicy profile=qc-ops
```

But what is happening when i run the script is

```
dev-ops arn:aws:iam::37928052:policy/PointPolicy
dev-ops arn:aws:iam::56433041:policy/PointPolicy
dev-ops arn:aws:iam::18225202:policy/PointPolicy
dev-ops arn:aws:iam::908231278:policy/PointPolicy
dev-ops arn:aws:iam::441043922:policy/PointPolicy
dev-ops arn:aws:iam::227661653:policy/PointPolicy


pro-ops arn:aws:iam::37928052:policy/PointPolicy
pro-ops arn:aws:iam::56433041:policy/PointPolicy
pro-ops arn:aws:iam::18225202:policy/PointPolicy
pro-ops arn:aws:iam::908231278:policy/PointPolicy
pro-ops arn:aws:iam::441043922:policy/PointPolicy
pro-ops arn:aws:iam::227661653:policy/PointPolicy

qc-ops arn:aws:iam::37928052:policy/PointPolicy
qc-ops arn:aws:iam::56433041:policy/PointPolicy
qc-ops arn:aws:iam::18225202:policy/PointPolicy
qc-ops arn:aws:iam::908231278:policy/PointPolicy
qc-ops arn:aws:iam::441043922:policy/PointPolicy
qc-ops arn:aws:iam::227661653:policy/PointPolicy
```

I have 40+ aws accounts so i will create a loop for "profile" at the same time policy arn should get with the same profile account ID.

How can I achieve the output like this.

Comment: Please provide a sample of `../../.aws/config` and `policy_arn` (not necessarily the whole files)

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question Hashim, please edit your question and let us know what is the logic of getting expected output in your question as its not clear as of now, thank you.

Comment: @hashimvayalar Please read [bashfaq How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: I am sorry for that I have updated @RavinderSingh13

Comment: I am lost. You do `cat ../../.aws/config` and `cat policy_arn` and you showed file named `arn` and file named `profile`. Are they related somehow? You also tell `I want to iterate the first line in "profile" to the first line in "arn"` - then use those files, not `../../.aws/config` and `policy_arn`. Ach these are _variable names_, not _file names_, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with:

```
grep 'profile' ../../.aws/config | paste - policy_arn
```

The `paste` command joins two files as columns, and here we use `-` for the first filename to represent it coming from `stdin` (ie it comes from the pipe). No loop is required.

Comment: I also suspect this is the output OP intended to have. As an additional note, adding the flag `-d' '` to your `paste` command will produce a space separated output, as shown in the expected output of the question